# How to authenticate both the web app and backend with Google/OAuth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I am trying to write an application that:

1. In a browser, authenticates a user with a Google account.
2. Calls a backend service.
3. Backend access user's drive (and some other things) and then returns JSON.

Frontend: copied some example from the web, can authenticate without issues.
Backend: Node.js/Passport.js. Copied the code from an example, can authenticate.

But how do I authenticate a user in the browser and then do an API call so the API may access the Google Drive? What is the expected flow?

A. Web app authenticates the users then passes id_token to the server?
Can't find how to implement this on a server...
or:
B. Server sends app to, say, `/auth/google/` on the same server, then app gets a token from server?

Answer (score 0):

Think of OAuth2 as a permission delegation protocol - user (Resource owner) authenticates and gives a consent to passing an access token (or some other tokens) to the OAuth2 client that initiated the process. When the client receives the access token, it can act on behalf of he user and access resources on a resource server (Google Drive).

So if your backend wants to access Google Drive, the cleanest way would be to make your backend an OAuth2 client, that redirects a user to Google auth server and then receives an auth code. The client must ask for scopes that will allow it to access Google Drive. The auth code can be exchanged for an access token. To access Google Drive, the backend needs to send a valid access token in the Authorization HTTP header of the request.

If you need the tokens on your frontend as well, you can use it as an OAuth2 client and pass them to the backend in an HTTP header.